# Filter through dynamically inserted td elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to filter through dynamically inserted "td" elements in the table element within the HTML. I want the user to be able to type in text within the filter input field and if the text matches any of the td elements text content I want to those td elements displayed. I created the "filter" method within the "Music" constructor the last method within the constructor, furthermore, I called the filter method within the "filter field event listener" the last bit of code in the script. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks (I understand this is a lot of code but I wanted to give some context to my question!)

```js
//JavaScript
// Music Constructor
class Music {
  constructor(artist, song, album, genre) {
    this.artist = artist;
    this.song = song;
    this.album = album;
    this.genre = genre;
  }


  // Add song to music list
  addSongToList(music) {
    // Select Music List in UI
    const list = document.querySelector('#music-list');
    //Create Element
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.className = 'row-data';
    row.innerHTML =
      ` <td class="tbl-data">${music.artist}</td>
                    <td class="tbl-data">${music.song}</td>
                    <td class="tbl-data">${music.album}</td>
                    <td class="tbl-data">${music.genre}</td>`;
    list.appendChild(row);
  }

  // Clear Fields
  clearFields() {
    artist.value = '';
    song.value = '';
    album.value = '';
    genre.value = '';
  }

  // Delete Song
  deleteSong(target) {
    if (target.className === 'tbl-data') {
      target.parentElement.remove();
    }
  }

  //Filter songs by genre
  filter(input) {
    let songs = document.querySelectorAll('td');
    songs.forEach(function(song) {
      let songRow = song.textContent;
      if (songRow.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
        song.style.display = 'block';
      }
    })

  }

  // Welcome message
  static welcomeMsg(message, className) {
    // Create element
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'welcomeMessage';
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
    // Select parent
    const parent = document.querySelector('.container');
    const card = document.querySelector('.card');
    parent.insertBefore(div, card);

    setTimeout(function() {
      div.remove();
    }, 6000);
  }
}

// Document object event listener
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Welcome Message call
  Music.welcomeMsg('Welcome, enter your favorite artist, songs, albums, and genre in the input fields below! Double click songs you want to delete once added!');
})

// Event listener on Form
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  // UI Form Input
  const artist = document.querySelector('#artist').value;
  const song = document.querySelector('#song').value;
  const album = document.querySelector('#album').value;
  const genre = document.querySelector('#genre').value;

  //Instantiate Music Constructor 
  const music = new Music(artist, song, album, genre);
  console.log(music);
  // Call prototype method
  music.addSongToList(music);
  music.clearFields()
  e.preventDefault();
})

// Music list event listener
document.querySelector('#music-list').addEventListener('dblclick', function(e) {
  //Instantiate Music Constructor 
  const music = new Music(artist, song, album, genre);
  //Remove method call
  music.deleteSong(e.target);
});

// Filter field event listener 
document.querySelector('#filter').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  let filter = document.querySelector('#filter').value;
  //Instantiate Music Constructor 
  const music = new Music(artist, song, album, genre);
  // Call filter prototype method
  music.filter(filter);
});
```

```html
//HTML

<body>
  //Container with the input fields
  <div class="primary-container ">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="text-center mb-3">Favorite Music Archive</h1>
      <div class="card mx-auto px-4">
        <form action="">
          <label for="basic-url" class="form-label form-text">Music Artist</label>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3"><img src="icons/guitar.png" alt="artist" class="icon-img"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="artist" placeholder="Enter Musical Artist">
          </div>
          <label for="basic-url" class="form-label form-text">Song</label>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3"><img src="icons/music.png" alt="song" class="icon-img"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="song" placeholder="Enter Song">
          </div>
          <label for="basic-url" class="form-label form-text">Album</label>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3"><img src="icons/music-album.png" alt="Album" class="icon-img"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="album" placeholder="Enter Album or Single">
          </div>
          <label for="basic-url" class="form-label form-text">Genre</label>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3"><img src="icons/dj.png" alt="genre" class="icon-img"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="genre" placeholder="Enter Genre">
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center p-3">
            <button type="submit" class="subBtn">Submit Song</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-container">
    //Filter Input field
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><img src="icons/filter.png" alt="filter" class="icon-img"></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control filter-input" placeholder="Filter by genre" id="filter"> //Filter Input End
      <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr class="row-head">
            <th scope="col">Artist</th>
            <th scope="col">Song</th>
            <th scope="col">Album</th>
            <th scope="col">Genre</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        // Dynamically inserted TD elements will go into tbody
        <tbody id="music-list">
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to search a table (if you are open to using JQuery) is to use [JQuery DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/). It allows you to search a table quite easily. All you have to do is include JQuery and the JQuery DataTable CDN to get it working:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-secondary table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr class="row-head">
                    <th scope="col">Artist</th>
                    <th scope="col">Song</th>
                    <th scope="col">Album</th>
                    <th scope="col">Genre</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Some artist 1</td>
                    <td>Some song 1</td>
                    <td>Some album 1</td>
                    <td>Some genre 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Some artist 2</td>
                    <td>Some song 2</td>
                    <td>Some album 2</td>
                    <td>Some genre 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Some artist 3</td>
                    <td>Some song 3</td>
                    <td>Some album 3</td>
                    <td>Some genre 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                // Initiate the data table:
                $("#myTable").DataTable();
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

All you do is initiate it as a DataTable and it will automatically provide a search input (that live searches the table), "Show X Entries", "Showing X to Y of Z entries", and pagination. Now, you can customize it further to only show the input search box if you would like, but I will refrain from further elaboration unless you are interested.

This will also work for any dynamically created td tags. If you are only dynamically inserting td tags before user interaction with the table (so right on render), then you can simply initialize the table (`$("#myTable").DataTable();`) after you are done dynamically creating the table's tbody. If you are steadily inserting td tags even after the table has been rendered for the user to use, then you can add rows dynamically and redraw the DataTable:

```js
let table = $("#myTable").DataTable();

// This adds a new row after the DataTable was already rendered:
table.row.add([
   "Some artist 4",
   "Some song 4",
   "Some album 4",
   "Some genre 4"
]);

// This redraws the DataTable to reflect those changes:
table.draw();
```